# React Native import external stylesheet

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For some reason I can import the style if it's within the project director:

`import styles from '../../../styles/style`

But once I try to import from an external stylesheet, using the following line of code:

```
import styles from 'https://.....js';
```

I receive the error "Requiring unknown module https://.....js. If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager."

Is there a different method to importing externally? Thanks!